# Nivoslider interfering with navigation list menu

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

I'm using nivoslider along with a vertical navigation menu on the same page. Nivoslider appears to be freezing at random intervals and disabling my navigation menu. However other links on the page work fine. I'm having this issue in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Oddly enough it doesn't appear to be happening in IE. I have no idea what is happening or how to fix it. Any ideas? [Link](http://www.goodwin.edu/templateDraft/Admissions/)

Comment: Share some code. Like the HTML of your navigation.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I completely forgot to include that. Here is a [link](http://www.goodwin.edu/templateDraft/Admissions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's what's happening.

When the squared effect happens, some invisible tiles overlap on top of the vertical navigation.

If you want to see for yourself just add this css rule

```
.nivo-box { border:1px solid #ff0000; }
```

When it overlaps the vertical navigation, it doesn't allow a click underneath.

So what you need to do is simply add a rule to #slider-wrapper.theme-Admissions

```
#slider-wrapper.theme-Admissions { overflow:hidden; }
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never figured this out.